# Can somebody explain why this doesn't work?

Tags: typescript

The idea is to enforce not using certain fields in the object passed to the function, and you can use anything else (that's why the `extends`)

```
type ForbiddenFields = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
type Data = { [K in ForbiddenFields]?: never };

function foobar<T extends Data>(data: T): void {
  //...
}

const obj = { x: 1, y: 2 };
foobar(obj); // Type '{ x: 1, y: 2 }' has no properties in common with type Data
```

Why do I get the

> Type '{ x: 1, y: 2 }' has no properties in common with type Data

if the function is just expecting an object *extending* `Data`, wouldn't it be the same as saying `<T extends {}>` but just enforcing that if a `ForbiddenField` is specified it has to be `never` -- therefore, can't be there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is running afoul of the [weak type detection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#weak-type-detection) introduced in TypeScript 2.4.  Since `Data`'s properties are *all* [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties), the compiler considers it a "weak type" and therefore not compatible with any other type unless there's at least one overlapping property.  This, like [excess property detection for object literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) isn't really a type system soundness feature; it's more of a linter rule that stops things that it thinks are probably mistakes.

The release notes for weak type detection say:

> Since this is a breaking change, you may need to know about the workarounds which are the same as those for strict object literal checks:
>
> - Declare the properties if they really do exist.
> - Add an index signature to the weak type (i.e. `[propName: string]: {}`).
> - Use a type assertion (i.e. `opts as Options`).

We can use the second suggestion and add a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures); since we don't want to restrict any of these other properties, we should probably make the values [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) (since even the type safe `unknown` would end up excluding interface types without index signatures, which we don't want to do).  It could look like this:

```
interface AnyData extends Data {
  [k: string]: any;
}

function foobar<T extends AnyData>(data: T): void {
  //...
}
```

And you can verify that things behave as desired:

```
const obj = { x: 1, y: 2 };
foobar(obj); // okay

const obj2 = { x: 1, y: 2, c: 3 };
foobar(obj2); // error!  Types of property 'c' are incompatible.

interface Baz {
  x: 1,
  y: 2
}
declare const baz: Baz;
foobar(baz); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9gJwEYEsAmaIDsYogGzQGcoBeKAcgEMKoAfSpWhigYwoG4AoUSKAESrAqZKAG8oAbQDSUFFliJUGbLgLEAugH4AXFCwQAbhARQAvt3nATAMyqtoAQSwhBwqBAAe1rMQFCRMS4oKQBrPSJgBHkAcw09KhduMy4uGwBXLFZgFDgFGzg4JCoEAB4AFQ9vbD9nVwCAPgAKNAC9coBKPUM4dHFgqAB6QYA6Ma4U1NY8yKgigCtRCU89AEYAGigQPQAmc24CopKmhY6OIcG50KoQKZngOaR5vfJltc3tqB3N1j0AZn2aUKxQQJyeOzOFw8CAQiAAhCFyuAICQ4DYoGBYZAEKBKOwoCVoPJpgBbMBCFBIfAQEapKy2ezQABCVAAXv0QisoBsBp8dhMuJhWPhCVBplhZsVWXoWayDsDjlLIcMrjdUkA)

Comment: Accepting this answer as it explains about the **weak type detection** and the fact of having all optional properties is "not valid" to TS (wtf). That's the key. However, cheers to @Rubydesik for providing a clever solution.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't tell you why Typescript doesn't consider `{ x: number, y: number }` to extend `{ a?: never }` - for some reason it requires the 'a' key to be present on the first type for some reason.

to solve your problem, however, requires only a simple modification of the function signature:

`function foobar<T>(data: T & Data): void`

Comment: Oh, clever. I remember thinking something like that but not trying it in the end.